# Update with nested case for previous dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, case

I have a table with following columns:

```
Document_ID, Customer_ID, Date, LoanedMoney.
```

I've created a new `LoanedDate` column. I want to fill dates to `LoanedDate` in the following way:

1. If the previous `Date` or previous date doesn't exists (it doesn't means always -1 day) with the same `Document_ID` and `Customer_ID` is null -> copy `LoanedMoney` value and update with that value;
2. If the previous `Date` (it doesn't means always -1 day) with the same `Document_ID` and `Customer_ID` is not null -> copy it and update with that value;
3. Else set `NULL` to `LoanedDate`

My approximate logic to determine the previous Date (don't know how to put it in case statement):

```
SELECT TOP 1 Z1.Date
FROM DBANME Z1
LEFT JOIN DBNAME Z2
ON Z1.Document_ID = Z2.Document_ID AND Z1.Customer_ID = Z2.Customer_ID AND CONVERT(CHAR(8), Z1.Date, 112) < CONVERT(CHAR(8), Z2.Date, 112)
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

I have done something like this:

```
DECLARE @Min datetime, @Prev datetime
SELECT @Min = MIN(Date) FROM DBNAME     

UPDATE DBNAME
SET LoanedDate CASE

WHEN (LoanedMoney > 0) 
--  SET @Prev = 
    CASE WHEN @Prev IS NULL THEN Date
    ELSE @Prev
ELSE NULL
```

What's the best way to implement it?

What I have:

```
Document_ID, Customer_ID, Date, LoanedMoney, LoanedDate
1, 1, 2012-04-30, 30, NULL 
1, 1, 2012-04-29, 50, NULL 
1, 1, 2012-04-28, 50, NULL 
1, 1, 2012-04-27, 0, NULL
1, 1, 2012-04-26, 20, NULL
```

What I expect:

```
Document_ID, Customer_ID, Date, LoanedMoney, LoanedDate
1, 1, 2012-04-30, 30, 2012-04-28 
1, 1, 2012-04-29, 50, 2012-04-28 
1, 1, 2012-04-28, 50, 2012-04-28 
1, 1, 2012-04-27, 0, NULL -- Because LoanedMoney = 0
1, 1, 2012-04-26, 20, 2012-04-26
```

Comment: Can you add a few rows of sample data and expected results to your question?

Comment: Update your question, please. Don't write additional data in comments, it's so unreadable this way.

Comment: Sorry, done. Please have a look above.

Comment: How do you get `LoanedDate = 2012-04-28` in first row for `Date = 2012-04-30`? I can't really get it from previous explanation.

Comment: Because `LoanedMoney > 0` since 2012-04-28.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this - just a couple of correlated sub-queries enforcing all the rules. First sub-query is finding all dates smaller then current and second one is eliminating values after the newest LoanedMoney = 0. Select MIN from it, and use COALESCE to replace it with current date if it's null.

```
UPDATE z1
SET LoanedDate = 
    CASE WHEN LoanedMoney = 0 THEN NULL
         ELSE
          COALESCE ( 
             (SELECT MIN(DATE) 
                FROM DBNAME z2 
                WHERE z1.Customer_ID = z2.Customer_ID 
                    AND z1.Document_ID = z2.Document_ID 
                    AND z2.Date < z1.Date   
                    AND z2.Date > (SELECT MAX(DATE) 
                                    FROM dbo.DBNAME z3
                                    WHERE z3.Customer_ID = z2.Customer_ID 
                                        AND z3.Document_ID = z2.Document_ID 
                                        AND z3.Date < z1.Date
                                        AND z3.LoanedMoney = 0)

        ), Date) END
FROM dbo.DBNAME z1
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cdde1/1)**

**EDIT - Option2**

Here is another method, using different concepts like [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function and [recursive CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Might be a bit harder to understand, but it will outperform the first query on larger tables.

```
WITH CTE_Prep AS 
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Document_ID, Customer_ID ORDER BY [DATE]) RN
    FROM DBNAME
)
,RCTE AS 
(
    SELECT *,  CASE WHEN LoanedMoney>0 THEN Date END AS LoanedDate2
    FROM CTE_Prep 
    WHERE RN = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT p.*,  CASE WHEN p.LoanedMoney=0 THEN NULL 
                      ELSE CASE WHEN r.LoanedDate2 IS NULL THEN p.Date 
                                ELSE r.LoanedDate2 END 
                 END AS LoanedDate2
    FROM CTE_Prep p
    INNER JOIN RCTE r 
        ON p.Customer_ID = r.Customer_ID
        AND p.Document_ID = r.Document_ID
        AND p.RN = r.RN + 1
)
UPDATE z 
    SET z.LoanedDate = r.LoanedDate2
FROM RCTE r
INNER JOIN dbo.DBNAME z ON r.Customer_ID = z.Customer_ID
    AND r.Document_ID = z.Document_ID
    AND r.Date = z.Date;
```

**[SQLFiddleDEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cdde1/3)**

Comment: Seems it's more or less way to go. Thank you, especially for COALESCE! I haven't used it before.

Comment: Interesting, but It'll take a bit more time for me to get how it works. Thank you for your brilliant ideas - It's very helpful!